# startActivityForResult();

Tags: android

```
Intent emailSend = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"tonikg90@gmail.com"});
        emailSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Item Best Seller");


        emailSend.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, map1.toString());
        emailSend.setType("text/plain");

        //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailSend, "Send Email..."));

        setResult(RESULT_OK, emailSend); 
        finish();
        break;
```

after click sending Email Button, It's supposed to go to email service. But It immediately goes back to the first activity. How can I make it to mail service, and after click "send" then it returns back to the first activity, also with Toast says that "Email has been sent"

Answer (score 4):

First, remove comment from `startActivityForResult` method. Remember: start activity works asynchronously, so just after you used startActivityForResult, `setResult` and `finish` will be executed.

What you need to do then is to implement the `onActivityResult` method, and move `setResult` and `finish` to there. `onActivityResult` will be called when the email has been sent, thus it will get you back to your main activity.

Comment: it might be a dumb question, what to write in onActivityResult method as I don't how to refer to my emailSend intent.

Comment: I don't get your question... in fact, I don't see the `?` mark :P