# Finish class and get int from class finished to main class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a MainClass which one is the full app, when I click one button I go to another class (PopupValores) which one I make it looks like a popup. In this class I have a EditText where you type a integer and a button to close this class. My question is how to get that int typed in PopupClass and use it in MainClass. Heres the code for the PopupValores.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PopupValores extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView texto;
String mensaje;
EditText editable;
Button ok;
public static int cantidad;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popupvalores);

    ok = (Button) findViewById (R.id.Bok);
    texto = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
    editable = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    mensaje = editable.getText().toString();
    ok.setOnClickListener(this);

    ok.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    });


}

public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.Bok:

    String mensaje;
    mensaje = editable.getText().toString();

    cantidad = Integer.parseInt(mensaje);

    texto.setText("New value " + cantidad + ".");

    }
}
}
```

Then in my MainClass I click a button and it shows the int

```
int id, vaas = PopupValores.cantidad;
public void onClick (View v)
{   
posicion = (ImageCell) v;
seleccion = posicion.mCellNumber;

if (seleccion == -1){
    ....
    toast (id + " " + vaas);
    ....
}
}
```

But instead of showing the value declared in PopupValores it shows 0. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to call the popup Activity with `Activity.startActivityForResult()`
2. Once finishing the popup Activity, set the requested result via `Activity.setResult()` (you can save your data in the intent's bundle)
3. In your main Activity, override `onActivityResult` and retrieve the data

Answer (score 0):

Its called startActivityforResult
and has been answered soo many times here on stackoverflow Here is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473941/startactivityforresult)